# Will not closing read end of a pipe lead to "Broken pipe" on write end

Tags: linux, pipe

I have the following program (trimmed down version of my original code) to highlight what I am observing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        int pipefd[2];
        char buff[64];
        FILE *cmd_output_fd;
        int rval;
        int pid, child_status;

        rval = pipe(pipefd);
        assert(rval == 0);
        cout << "Pipe : " << pipefd[0] << ", " << pipefd[1] << endl;

        pid = fork();
        assert(pid >= 0);

        if (pid == 0) {
            // Child process - exec cksum

            dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);

            execlp("cksum", "cksum", "testout", nullptr);

            // If we are here, execlp() failed.
            assert(0);
            return 1;
        }

        close(pipefd[1]);

        // wait for child to finish up.
        wait(&child_status);
        if ((WIFEXITED(child_status)) && (WEXITSTATUS(child_status) != 0)) {
            std::cout << "cksum utility finished with error, exit status "
                      << WEXITSTATUS(child_status) << endl;
        }

        // If all is well, cksum has checksum of testout in it's stdout (pipefd[1])

        cmd_output_fd = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r");
        assert(cmd_output_fd != NULL);  // Error   (NOTE 1)

        if (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), cmd_output_fd) == NULL) {
            assert(0);      // Error
        }
        fclose(cmd_output_fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Once in a rare while, I encounter the following error:

```
Pipe : 22, 24
cksum: write error: Broken pipe
cksum utility finished with error, exit status 1
```

When the cksum utility hits the "Broken pipe" error (1), cmd_output_fd is NULL (2) (triggers assert() in line marked Note 1).  My guess is during the loop when the error is encountered, pipefd[0] (the reader end) gets closed somehow, prior to cksum being launched.  This would explain the two observations - cksum not able to write to pipefd[0], and fdopen() fails.

If my assumption is correct, what could be causing pipefd[0] to be closed?

Just a wild guess, could this issue be caused because I am not doing a close(pipefd[0]) at the end of the for loop.  If so, how?

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Have you managed to reproduce the problem with the snippet you posted?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am guessing the issue could be timing related.  But I see where you are might be coming from.  I will try to change the code snippet in attempt to repro.  Is there any debug code I can add to verify my suspision?

Comment: I would `strace` the program, and run it over and over until the problem appears. This would show exactly what's going on from a syscall point of view.